# Ubuntu 16.04.1 file has errors and won't boot

Tags: boot, asus, error-handling

I created a pendrive for Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS (64-bit) installation, and it runs fine in my old HP Pavillion g6 (in which I use Windows) but I cannot boot it in my new Asus R510V (just with FreeDOS), I have checked the file in the latter and it just says that there are 2 errors in the file, and to press any key to boot, and then there is only a black screen with this "[   5.456513] nouveau 0000:01:00.0 priv: HUBO: 10ecc0 fffffff 1b40822c)".

I would like to know how can I fix those errors it indicates.

I am sorry if this question is redundant. I

Answer (score 0):

I dont think there are real errors because you wrote: "it runs fine in my old HP Pavillion g6"
Possibilities why your Asus wont boot from a pendrive:
- have you the latest BIOS version?
- do you know that you have to push ESC-key during startup to show a boot menu, so you can choose the pendrive? (This is the case in my Asus laptop.)
- If there is also a DVD drive present, you can use an installation DVD with Ubuntu.
- If there is also a DVD drive present, you can insert the Plop-CD to help you to start from any device, also a pendrive.
BTW: have you checked the checksum after downloading the ISO?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, yes, I have chosen the pendrive in the initial menu. I am really ignorant on informatics, so I am learning on the go. I am going to check the checksum, and I do not know about the BIOS. Many thanks.